# Can a Toshiba Canvio Basics 1TB USB 3.0 external hard drive be converted to use as an internal hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have same drive as in the link bellow spare after upgrading.
I'm going to get a desktop and I've been looking into what parts I already have that I could use to lower the cost.

[Link to hard drive on argos.co.uk](http://www.argos.co.uk/product/1336577?cmpid=GS001&_$ja=tsid:59158%7Ccid:200223050%7Cagid:12488287010%7Ctid:aud-144400486596:pla-296172214765%7Ccrid:66128552210%7Cnw:g%7Crnd:18087299340770055787%7Cdvc:c%7Cadp:1o2&gclid=CjwKCAjw_dTMBRBHEiwApIzn_KrfNDvkFLfczmFqSLa8jrBSkQSXnHGEMpT3vaQutkayATZUgJwhhRoCqqcQAvD_BwE)

Can this particular drive be used as an internal hard drive?

Comment: The only way to determine that would be to open up the enclosure and look at the actual HDD contained within it.  This of course depending if that is a destructive process break the enclosure itself.

Comment: No you can't : Canvio disks are meant to be used only on USB connectors by design, see that video on chunking a canvio external drive youtu.be/vagCWvdCOVU?t=130
If you want to do that, you shall go to other brands like that one : https://youtu.be/qTJQr7Ur9SA?t=145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can indeed do that. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UTowCeFLyw) of someone 'shucking' another Toshiba Canvio.

However, in the comments, someone posted:

> NOTE:  The latest releases of the Canvio 2.5" series are PROPRIETARY
> DRIVES.  The drives themselves no longer have a separate USB 2/3
> controller:  It's incorporated onto the HD's controller board
> DIRECTLY.
>
> Make sure that the PHYSICAL SIZE of the external housing is at least
> 3/4" longer than the usual 2.5" hard drive BEFORE buying it,
> otherwise, you'll be stuck with a "permanent external-ONLY drive."
>
> This is why few technically oriented people buy WD 2.5" externals any
> more...they're ALL designed with the USB controller as a part of the
> HD controller board.

All things considered, you should really consider using an SSD to install your programs, if at all possible. It makes your computer a **lot** faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. SSD is pretty expensive though and I want plenty of space for programs. How about if i buy a 2TB SSHD drive rather than a HHD?

Comment: Would that make a lot of difference (but with out the price tag). It's mostly ram the CPU that seems to be the bottleneck on my current HDD laptop. Though its got 2 i7 cores not the 4 i5s i was thinking and there 1/2 the speed and its got 8GB ram where as I was going to get 16GB and there should be ports to expand that if needed.

Comment: A SSHD is an option as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ready to get into the internals of hard drive you can do that 
[how to convert a USB HDD drive board to SATA HDD drive](https://youtu.be/2eKYB6bRN7k?t=467) and you will need to invest money into another board, and the tools + software required. Is it worth it ?

[Quick and dirty way](https://youtu.be/L_LVrQ20Geg)

[Connexion scheme](https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/31428041_1810787635610004_1916886733618675712_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=fuOYzs4peygAX9wqQPx&oh=bdb0d243f59e6d1194d1e145146373c0&oe=5EBBA115)