# How can one know which portable external HDD cán be turned into an internal HDD ("shucked")?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sata

If you open up the housing of most **2.5 inch external HDDs**, (superfluous: those that don't need and extra power source) the disk inside can be used as an internal HDD, provided it has a *SATA connection*. One removes the SATA-to-micro-usb-3.0-connector, *et voila*!
It seems that some HDD's (by Toshiba and Verbatim for example) have a *micro USB 3.0 card*, so those can NOT be used inside laptops or network devices.

Question: How can we know before opening or better yet, before buying whether such an external portable HDD has a SATA connection and nót a *micro USB 3.0 card*? So, what specific characteristic in the specification does one look at? Interface?

Follow-up: What other issues might prevent us from shucking the HDD's?

Comment: https://www.toshiba-storage.com/products/toshiba-portable-hard-drives-canvio-basics-2/?pdf   78 x 109 x 14 mm (including its enclosure). They won't tell you the dimensions of the drive inside the enclosure because they don't expect you to shuck it.

Comment: https://www.newegg.com/insider/does-shucking-hard-drives-even-make-sense/

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1241862/can-a-toshiba-canvio-basics-1tb-usb-3-0-external-hard-drive-be-converted-to-use/1241867

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UTowCeFLyw

Comment: There's another caveat, even if everything fits mechanically & electronically - sometimes External enclosure 'fake' the bock size [this use to be for simplicity/compatibility on older computers]. You *can* use the drive directly in a computer, but you will need to fully re-format before you can use it so it won't work if there's data on it you need.

Comment: @Gantendo - they also won't tell you the dimensions of the drive inside because the spec is not guaranteed to be fixed. They'll use whatever drives they have available at the time. It all gets hidden in a 'sekrit box' that few consumers will ever think to look inside ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin What's the bock size? And if you mean the b**L**ock size, how can an external enclosure alter that? Most importantly: What does that tell us about the connectivity, does it indicate SATA or micro-USB-C?  Or doesn't it mean a thing?

Comment: @Gantendo doesn't a 14mm thickness indicate a 9.5 mm  height of the internal version?

Comment: @Gantendo the canvio question is not similar, since it focuses on a single example while the OP seems to be looking for a general rule or detection method.

Comment: @GwenKillerby That specific drive was in an older revision of the question...

Comment: Yup, typo, I meant block size. idk how it does it, but it does. Added to the other caveats it really means you'll never know until you open it & test it.

Answer (score 2):

Not every.

It depends really on the design of the disk. Some may have SATA port, or some may have different electronics between port and the disk inside.

Mostly many of them will be SATA but you are not sure unless opening the disk (and having void warranty) and checking, and connecting it would be a sure situation as this may be modified SATA.

So unless you open the disk, connect it and check the data on disk - you are unsure.

The thickness is the second parameter which can block you from putting the disk into a laptop.

Also laptop can have or will not have desired space for each drive's thickness.

Comment: Also, note that if you build consumer external hard drives, you probably don't walk into a hardware store and buy 20 HDDs off the shelf – you talk to the people making or distributing the SSDs and make a contract to deliver their drives at scale. Typically, you want to get them cheaper than retail, because they're going to be used in lower-performance settings, anyway. So, if not simply always buying the stock surplus of last-generation drives, you might make an arrangement with the HDD manufacturer to deliver drives that were categorized as lower-performing during manufacturing testing.

Comment: (hard drives use error-correcting codes extensively, because even the most expensive server hard drive makes a lot of bit errors, physically, which mustn't be left uncorrected; luckily, math allows us to correct bit errors through computational effort and added redundancy, i.e. more bits to store the data than the data had bits). There's variations in the amount of raw bit errors, and thus variations in the maximum sustained read speed including iterative error correction schemes, of hard drives. You don't need a great fast hard drive for a USB3 use case. So, you get the ones that the vendor

Comment: didn't feel like putting on the market as HDDs on their own – to protect their brand. Wouldn't want to {insert brand name here} series of {insert high-end HDD series name} to perform badly in a test, would you? But that also means that they can drop features from the platter that the USB host doesn't use anyways. Smaller/slower caches, less reporting, no command reordering … would all be legal to have in an external drive.

Comment: So, buying an external 2.5" USB drive to take out the sata drive within – not a great idea, to be honest.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would guess that OP has that drive laying around gathering dust and wondered if they could use it as an internal drive.

Comment: @Gantendo Ah, no. It's like is described in your article: economics. External HDD's are cheaper than internal HDD, however crazy that might sound. I see a 4TB going for € 77 and a 2TB for €59

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't think one can say as a hard & fast rule that shucking HDD's is *always* bad because it's cheaper & depending on what's inside, it's actually a very **good** idea. **Íf** you claim producers dump their bad HDD's into enclosures (for which target market?) that doesn't sound very convincing. For one thing, diskmakers' reputation **also** depends on the quality of their external portables, not just their internal HDD's. Especially since these days, laptops have tiny inital starter SSDs. Please provide more evidence for this than your personal dim views of disk fabricators.

Comment: @GwenKillerby but the *cheap* external drives are usually not marketed and branded by the disk manufacturers, but by third parties.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Do you really think Seagate wants to be known for selling lousy samsungs? Therefore, you saying 'oooh! thirds parties, eh?' doesn't alter your argument by very much, or, you know... **not at all**, since third parties also have reputations to uphold and protect. See this video where someone asks Seagate  directly about this, their reaction is rahter  ... **odd**   
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RiIQnoidCIA&t=632s

Comment: @MarcusMüller I re-stumbled upon this and what I noticed was this *"if you build consumer ext HDDs, you probably don't walk into a hardware store and buy 20 HDDs off the shelf "* ---- The idea that anyone would think that is..... let's call it odd, so not an argument. *"the people making or distributing the SSDs"* --- this not about SSDs at all.  *"because they're going to be used in lower-performance settings, anyway"* --- ext. HDDs are gonna be used for fast backups of lots of data. That's not "lower performance" but you can call it that, if you want.

Comment: @MarcusMüller And I get what you're saying, external HDD's are not seen, **anymore**  as OS drives, but shucked drives are gonna be used for storage of large games and 4K video, not for OS work. Therefor your argument falls flat.
*"you might make an arrangement with the HDD manufacturer to deliver drives that were categorized as lower-performing during manufacturing testing"* In essence you're saying: Good drives go to internal heaven, bad drives go to external hell. Seems unlikely that significant amounts of drives test measurably worse. But, if you have any proof, let's see it.